# Good pattern for async execution in decorator

Tags: javascript, node.js, decorator

I have a decorator function that sets up a database. However, since decorators can't be async, it does not work well.

```
export default function databaseDecorator (options) {
  const db = new Database({
    url: options.url
  });

  function checkDatabase () {
    // promisified functions that make sure DB exists
  }

  async function checkCollection () {
    // checks that DB collection exists
  }

  checkCollection()
  checkDatabase()

  return (target) => {
    /* does decorator business here */

    return target
  }
}
```

What pattern can I use to make sure the `check*` functions complete before I decorate the target and return it? Thank you.

EDIT: The solution need not be in the decorator itself. If there's a better solution by initializing the db somewhere else, that's OK.

Comment: `await check*` ?

Comment: You can't. As soon as you enter `async` land, every function must be async or be able to work with promises. If you did something like `var foo = databaseDecorator(options)(function() { ... })` then the best you can do is assign a promise to `foo` that resolves to a function.

Comment: @GabrielBleu Can't use await outside and `async` function.

Comment: Why decorators can't be async ?

Comment: @FelixKling How could I then export that and use it as a decorator after it's resolved?

Comment: @GabrielBleu I believe it's because according to the spec they return a constructor, not a Promise. Async functions return a promise.

Comment: I don't think it's possible but I'm not sure. The check should probably be inside the function you are returning (and that function would be async).

Comment: @FelixKling that's the constructor, which can't be async.

Comment: How is the decorator dependant on the checks? won't it decorate if thy are not ready, or will it do a different change depending on that result? or does it only affect the results of the function/getter/setter you add inside the decorator?

Comment: @Thomas It affects the functions I'm adding to the decorated class. I'm using the databases functions there, so if the collection and DB aren't there, it will throw an error.

Comment: then how about making a promise `let dbReady = checkDatabase.then(checkCollection);` and in your decorated function `value: function(){ return dbReady.then(/*yourLogic*/ )}`

Comment: @Thomas The only problem with that is I have many functions. I'm already doing that with another function, `checkIndexes`, but I only need that once.

Comment: either that or something like `checkDB.then(/* start the decorating action */)` like in `$(document).ready(/* your code goes here */)` just for the DB

Comment: @Thomas I will try it, but I think returning the target will still happen before the decorating actions. EDIT: Indeed, the target is not decorated with this pattern.